# Socket server keeps listening but no response is received

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following code, and with any valid address or port, the code keeps listening, but either doesn't receive any response or doesn't print it.

```
import socket, threading

bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 39832

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))

server.listen(5)
print(f"[*] Listening on {bind_ip}: {bind_port}")

def handle_client(client_socket):
    
    response = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(f"[*] Recieved: {response}")

    client_socket.send("ACK!")
    client_socket.close()

while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    print(f"[*] Accepted connection from: {addr[0]}: {addr[1]}")
    client_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,))
    client_handler.start()
```

I can't find the problem as the book I am reading uses the same code but receives a response.

Comment: So how are you connecting to the server?

Comment: For me the code receives the data but throws an exception in `client_socket.send("ACK!")` because it should be `b"ACK!"` (bytes not string). I have no idea what you are doing different, since you are not providing information what you do in the first place (specifically what your client does) - you only show some code dump.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am currently learning network programming and all my code is doing is bind to an IP, receive some data, and print it. I tried `b"ACK!"` but still nothing is printed.

Comment: @Naddy7706: to repeat myself: *"I have no idea what you are doing different, since __you are not providing information what you do in the first place (specifically what your client does)__ - you only show some code dump."*. If you want others be able to help you, then you need to provide the necessary information.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich All I am doing is to connect to an ip, receive some data, and print it. No further use.

Comment: @Naddy7706: Since the server code works fine for me the problem is likely in how exactly you *"connect to an ip, receive some data, and print it"*. Again (and for the last time): if you don't provide the __exact__ and __reproducible__ way you do this one cannot help you.